# How do I find roots of the 3rd order polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

$$5x^3 - 21x^2 - 11x + 3 = 0$$

I am not allowed to use a graphical calculator on the exam

Comment: Just write two dollars before and after the equation. Other user has done it for you.

Comment: cubic formula (or numerical methods)

Comment: @ajotatxe I see, thank you

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "solve"? Finding the roots? If you want an expression with radicals, there is a rather complicated formula. If you want approximations there are some good numerical methods.

Comment: Irritatingly, $3$ would be a solution, found through the rational roots theorem, if only that constant term were $+6$ instead of $+3$.

Comment: @ajotatxe yes, I have to find the roots

Comment: @BrianTung according to the key, the solution is : {-0,646; 0,2; 4,65}

Comment: @TatiaGelashvili: Are you sure you've recorded this equation properly?  Those are not solutions to the equation provided.

Comment: @BrianTung a silly mistake of mine, sorry. I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Either use numerical methods, or graphing calculator, or if you want exact form

see [The Cubic Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html), by the way it's too complicated to remember or to evaluate by hand.

I would suggest using [Wolfy](https://www.wolframalpha.com) for this purpose.

Comment: The problem is that I have an exam, where these problems come pretty often and we are not allowed to use graphical calculators, so ..

Comment: @TatiaGelashvili Be assured that no exam will ever ask you to find out non-trivial roots of a polynomial of degree $>2$. The cubic in your exam either will definitely have at least one trivial root. (Like $-2,-1,0,1,2, \frac 12$)

Comment: @TatiaGelashvili Or if you have studied calculus, they may ask nature of roots,( ...like one positive real other two imaginary)

Comment: {-0,646; 0,2; 4,65} this is the solution according to the key.

Comment: I have never really studied calculus and this is just the placement test for the university :(

Comment: You have definitely typed wrong question because according to WolframAlpha, [roots are different](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5x%5E3+-+12x%5E2+-+11x+%2B+3+%3D+0)

Comment: So silly, I have fixed it